# how to remove focus on tab key press on the close button on jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i remove the focus on close button in jquery dialog when tab key is pressed.For buttons i have used tab-index=-1 and it worked. 
Attaching the

```
 $('.ui-widget-content').blur();
 $('.ui-widget-content :button').blur();
 $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close :link').blur();
 $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close :button').blur();
 $('.ui-icon').blur();            
 $('.ui-icon-closethick').blur();
 $('.ui-dialog').removeClass('ui-state-focus');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bharatgillala/a0ft8dm3/1/

I have tried the above statements but did not work for me.

Comment: you tried http://api.jquery.com/off/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `tabindex="-1"` to close button and trigger blur event on it. You don't need most of the stuff you tried, it can be as simple as

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').attr('tabindex', '-1').blur();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/a0ft8dm3/4/